# Sprite Kit view setup crash (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skview

I have an UIView that i want to add a SKScene to. In the step were i declare "skView" it crashes.

```
var skView=view as SKView; 
var skScene=gameScene();
skView.presentScene(skScene)
```

Comment: Please check what `view` holds. It probably is not an `SKView` and therefore the type cast fails.

Comment: "view" is of type "UIView"

Answer (score 0):

The `as` operator doesn't work that way. In order to treat a value of one type `as` another type, two things need to be true:

- the second type needs to be more specific than the first
- the value needs to *actually be* of the second type.

You've got the first, but not the second. For example, if I give you something and all I say is that it's a `Car`, you're welcome to `accelerate()` it all you want (don't forget to `brake()` too), but if you want to `engageClutch()` you'll need to treat it `as` a `StickshiftCar`.  I may or may not have given you a `StickshiftCar`,  though—if what you actually have is something else, you can't just say "treat this like a stickshift" to make it one.

If you want to use an `SKView`, you'll first need to get yourself one. If your view is set up in a storyboard, use IB to make the view controller's root view an `SKView`. Then, in code, you can access `self.view` (which is just a `UIView` for all that property knows) and safely treat it `as` an `SKView`.